# Is there a repetition sign in Hangul?

Tags: hangul

By repetition sign, I mean something that is like `々`　in Japanese and Chinese.

In both Japanese and Chinese, `々` can be used to suggest a repetition of the previous character. For example,  `人人` can be written as `人々`. In Japanese, there is also a repetition sign for kanas (`ゝ`).

Therefore, I am wondering whether there is such a sign in Hangul so that `똑똑하다` can be written as something like `똑々하다`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in modern Korean. Your example was used in text occasionally during the Japanese occupation of Korea, but is not part of the official Korean language guidelines (source: https://namu.wiki/w/%EB%B0%98%EB%B3%B5%20%EB%B6%80%ED%98%B8)

Answer (score 0):

We don't use that symbol in one word or sentence.

However, in non-formal documents, use symbols that mean a full sentence or a full word iteration. `"`

For example,

| Name | Lunch Menu |
| --- | --- |
| 철수 | 햄버거 |
| 민수 | " |
| 정수 | " |
| 민지 | 김치찌개 |

`"`(means 햄버거) is interpreted as repeating the words(or sentence) written just before (above). In most cases, it is only used for actual handwriting, not computer typing.

Comment: They also seem to use 상동(上同) a lot on formal documents.